# Looping through Laravel routes on a certain domain?

Tags: php, laravel

I can't find anything in their documentation but can anyone tell me if you can loop through Laravel's routes by domain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Route::getRoutes()` to extract all registered routes.

```
    $routeList = Route::getRoutes();

    foreach ($routeList as $route)
    {
        $routeName =(string) $route->getName();

        if($routeName != '')
        {
            $fullUrl = route($routeName);

            if (strpos($fullUrl, "http://mydomain,com") === 0) 
            {
                echo "this uri belongs to mydomain.com";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, It seems getPath isn't a valid function? Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::getPath()

Comment: It requires "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;"

Comment: I've already added that, and it's "use Route;", still no luck even when trying your one.

Comment: It is Illuminate\Suuport... Are you sure? Try to use complete namespace.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. It still returns the same error.

Comment: Thank you it now works, but this still isn't an answer. I need to get all routes from a specific domain, not all domains.

Comment: Inside loop body, you can add if statement to check for any specific domains. Edited.

Comment: Uri returns the route path, not the domain it's currently on.